# How to use gurobi to describe the process of finding the rank of matrix without objective function？

Tags: optimization, gurobi, binary-variable, multi-objective-optimization

I have a general square matrix `[[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[0,0,0]]` (the element is on a binary field--Galois Fields) I want to find the rank of this matrix (like the function: `np.linalg.matrix_rank`). How can I describe this process using gurobi?

Due to the elements in the matrix being related to the variables in gurobi model, I can't use the function of Numpy directly.

I tried asking a question in the [Gurobi community](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/21492875907857-How-to-use-gurobi-to-describe-the-process-of-finding-the-rank-of-matrix) before and got a small model that worked. This model has an objective function to get the rank.

When I embedded it in my original big model (which already has an objective function), the original model affected the optimization process of the rank-finding process. That is, in this multi-objective optimization problem, the rank is always wrong.

This would render the entire model unusable since the rank should be a deterministic property of the matrix. But now because the optimization process can't get the best, the rank property becomes uncertain.

My original goal was to maximize a "GObj" that is >= 0. If this value equals 1, it means the model has a solution. In the big model, the rank is required several times (several rank-finding processes are also related to each other).

For the rank process to be optimal, I tried to adjust the priority of the object, but even though I set the priority of the rank-finding very high, I still got a lot of wrong ranks. Similarly, I try not to optimize the "GObj", just limit it to >=1 so that the model can have a solution. I still got a lot of wrong ranks. I also tried to make a lot of small adjustments, but nothing worked.

I think an easy-to-understand solution is to figure out how to describe the process of finding the rank of matrix **without objective function**. So how can I describe it without objective function?

If I don't change the way the rank is found, how can the modeling be done so that the rank-finding procedure is optimal while maximizing "GObj"?

To describe my problem in detail, I wrote a demo and uploaded it to Github: https://github.com/wenny-kiki/test_math

Answer (score 1):

In theory we can use the fact that rank = the number of non-zero singular values in a [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) (SVD).

```
import gurobipy as gp
import numpy as np

m = gp.Model()

p,q = 4,3 # as an example, overwritten for testing

# The matrix we want to calculate rank of
M = m.addMVar((p,q), lb=-float("inf"), name="M")

# # uncomment the following lines for testing
# A = np.random.randint(-2,2, size=(p,q))
# m.addConstr(M == A)

U = m.addMVar((p,p), lb=-float("inf"), name="U")

ub = np.zeros((p,q))
np.fill_diagonal(ub, np.inf)
lb = np.zeros((p,q))
np.fill_diagonal(lb, -np.inf)
S = m.addMVar((p,q), lb=lb, ub=ub, name="S")

V = m.addMVar((q,q), lb=-float("inf"), name="V")

m.addConstr(U@U.T == np.eye(p))
m.addConstr(V@V.T == np.eye(q))

aux = m.addMVar((p,q), lb=-float("inf"), name="aux")
m.addConstr(U@S == aux)
m.addConstr(aux@V == M)

nzpos = m.addVars(min(p,q), vtype="B")
nzneg = m.addVars(min(p,q), vtype="B")
for i in range(min(p,q)):
    m.addConstr((nzpos[i]==1)>>(S[i,i] >= 0.0001))
    m.addConstr((nzpos[i]==0)>>(S[i,i] <= 0.00009))
    m.addConstr((nzneg[i]==1)>>(S[i,i] <= -0.0001))
    m.addConstr((nzneg[i]==0)>>(S[i,i] >= -0.00009))

rank = m.addVar()
m.addConstr(rank == nzpos.sum() + nzneg.sum())
m.optimize()
```

In practice this is not going to work though, and Gurobi will complain that "Model contains variables with very large bounds participating in product terms".  We can introduce bounds on U (and V) but in doing so requires $UU^T = I$ to be replaced with $UU^T = aI$ for some non-zero scalar $a$ (and similarly for V). What you get is a model which will probably only be solvable for tiny matrices - not to mention be prone to numerical issues and hence incorrect results.